# JavaScript: how to build games

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Good evening,

I have been working hard the past few months perfecting my developing skills.  I worked through a bunch of tutorials, completed JS and Ruby Test First, created a 'trello' clone with backbone/rails, a web scraper, I made my own version of 'disqus' and a chat app similar to gchat.

The one thing I am really struggling at is creating something like a BlackJack game.  My dream would be to make a baseball simulation game where I get the result from the command line.

If anyone knows of any good tutorials for either card games in JS please link them.  If you have any ideas of how I can get over this hump as well I'd love to hear it, thanks!

Comment: Searching for links is off-topic on SO. Note that finding even semi-decent implementation of a game in JavaScript written in functional programming style would be very hard... You may want to search for code in more traditional functional languages like Haskell.

Comment: Side note: for future on-topic question please avoid adding text not related to concrete problem (like greetings, thank you, and "searched/tried hard").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure because I don't program javascript myself but this one looks pretty good:

[Simple Html 5 Card Game with Canvas and Javascript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h94LxovcBnc)

You could find more by google: card game development javascript

Anyway, look at others' games and learn from the source.
Good luck ;)